# Is it true that you had lied / lied to me

Tags: past-perfect, sentence-structure, reported-speech, past-simple

Suppose A lied to B and then B asks in order to make sure if it is true or not

Is it true that you lied to me?

Is it true that you had lied to me?

Comment: Why use *had lied" without additional context? Otherwise, simpler is better.

Comment: For the OP, suggested reading: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/canonical-post-2-what-is-the-perfect-and-how-should-i-use-it

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use **Past Perfect** *(had lied)* to speak about *a time earlier than before now* but this tense is mostly used *to make it clear that one event happened before another in the past*. But in a simple question that speaks about the past it is better to use the **Past Simple** *(lied)*.

Depending on what context you have you choose which tense to use.